# How to do append the 2nd child element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Update: I figured it out! I just had to remove the .cloneNode() on the JS and it gives me the correct value now. Check the bottom code for my solution.

I'm trying to append the 2nd child in this services-cell div. So the one with digital marketing text.

Here is my HTML code

```html
<div class="services-cell">
  <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="">
  <h1 class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```js
if (galleryImages) {
  galleryImages.forEach(function(image, index) {
        image.onclick = function() {
            console.log(image.firstElementChild);

            getLatestOpenedImg = index + 1;

            let container = document.body;
            let newImgWindow = document.createElement('div');
            container.appendChild(newImgWindow);
            newImgWindow.setAttribute('class', 'img-window');
            newImgWindow.setAttribute('onclick', 'closeImg()');

            let newImg = image.firstElementChild.cloneNode();
            newImgWindow.appendChild(newImg);
            newImg.classList.remove('services-cell_img');
            newImg.classList.add('popup-img');
            newImg.setAttribute('id', 'current-img');

            let newTextDiv = document.querySelector('.img-window');
            let newText = document.createElement('div');
            newTextDiv.appendChild(newText)
            newText.setAttribute('class', 'img-text');
            newText.innerHTML = 'Hello'

         //This code below is working and solved my issue
               let imgTextValue = image.children[1];
          newText.appendChild(imgTextValue);
       console.log(imgTextValue);
```

So right now the JavaScript creates the following code in my HTML below

```html
<div class="img-window" onclick="closeImg()">
  <img class="popup-img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="" id="current-img">
  <div class="img-text">Hello</div>
</div>
```

But I want to append the `<div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>` to be inside of my `<div class="img-text">Hello</div>`. Note I have multiple services-cells so each one has a different text, so that's why I need the 2nd child element from .services-cell so that it will show the correct text value.

so if everything works, the code that I'm trying to achieve would look like this

```html
<div class="img-window" onclick="closeImg()">
  <img class="popup-img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="" id="current-img">
  <div class="img-text">
    <h1 class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I updated the Javascript code with this

```
   let imgTextValue = image.children[1].cloneNode();
       newText.appendChild(imgTextValue);
       console.log(imgTextValue);
```

and this resulted in the following code

```
 <div class="img-window" onclick="closeImg()">
   <img class="popup-img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="" 
 id="current-img">
   <div class="img-text">
     <h1 class="services-cell_text"></h1>
   </div>
 </div>
```

So it's basically 99% there, but the problem is the text inside of the H1 is not showing up? I don't understand why if I'm targeting the 2nd child element and it clearly shows the  tag

Comment: Format the html code hard to tell which elements are childs of which

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to add an event listener in a loop, creating a closure over loop variables as you are there. But generally, just create your element and append it to the same element that you're currently setting the `innerHTML` or `textContent` to "Hello".

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new element. I'm trying to get the value which is this entire html tag `<div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>` so I don't know what to write in order to get that value cause appendChild only targets the img tag